# VIM "linespace" not working

Tags: vim, configuration, vi, putty

I want to increase the line-height ("linespace") in VIM.

The official command is:

```
set linespace=X
```

However, this does not work (no effect) when I put it into my .vimrc file

```
set t_Co=256
syntax on
colorscheme wombat256

set linespace=1             " line height
set nocompatible
set showmatch
set ignorecase
set showmode
set ts=4
set sw=4
set autoindent
set cindent
```

In case it makes a difference, I'm using **Putty** to connect to my Linux server.

Any idea how I can increase the line spacing of text in VIM when connected in from Putty?

Comment: What is supposed to happen when linespace=1? I tried setting linespace=2 on my Vim and nothing happened either. I'm running natively in Ubuntu.

Comment: @RobertMartin: It inserts X additional pixels of spacing between lines of text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`linespace` works only in GUI. You can't use it in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway of having similar functionality as 'linespace' in a terminal?

Comment: @nickb: Only if the terminal software provides an option to do that. AFAIK PuTTY doesn't.